# AXP223 (AXP20X) RSB (Reduced Serial Bus) Read/Write

Tags: arm

I am trying to figure out how to write to the registers on the AXP223 via the Reduced Serial Bus (RSB) via the linux command line. How do I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Still looking for answers! Here is the article to the protocol on Sunxi website. Does anybody know how to use it? https://linux-sunxi.org/Reduced_Serial_Bus